# What dose it give an error Logging permission denied?

Tags: logging, google-cloud-functions, permission-denied, google-cloud-iam

I have deployed a cloud function on GCP. The service account I am using for deploying my cloud function has the permission "Logs.writer". But still it gives me an error when I try to invoke that cloud function.

> "error details: name = ErrorInfo reason = IAM_PERMISSION_DENIED domain = iam.googleapis.com metadata = map[permission:logging.logEntries.create]"
> timestamp: "2024-01-28T03:33:06.830860Z"

I am attaching bellow the the screenshot of the service account to confirm the permission for logging to GCP
[image]

But I dont know why dose it give the error. Please help.

I am trying to invoke the cloud function but it's giving me the logging permission error.

Comment: Can you cross check and confirm if you have set the correct service account, resource and project.

Comment: Yes I do have logging Admin permission to my account

Comment: Hi Sai Chandara Gadde I really appreciate your efforts. I was using a wrong service account for it but I did not know that. Your solution helped me...!

Comment: As your issue is resolved please consider accepting (✔️) or upvoting it. I'd really appreciate it. Have a great day, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You have required permission for logging assuming you have set the correct project and service account. Below troubleshooting steps can help you to resolve your issue:

1. As per this [document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/troubleshooting#identity):

> Invoking a Cloud Functions function that has been set up with [restricted access](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing) requires an [ID token](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/openid-connect#obtainuserinfo). Access tokens or refresh tokens do not work.

So try manually generating tokens by following this [official document](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/securing/authenticating#generating_tokens_manually).

2. If you are using python update the code to attach the Cloud Logging handler by following this [document](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/setup/python#connecting_the_library_to_python_logging).